# instanceof function parameter returns false in Typescript/Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to find out how to get the type of an Object if it was passed as a parameter in my function.

For example you have following code

```
getTypeOfAnimal(animal){
   console.log(animal instanceof Cat)
   console.log(animal instanceof Bear)
}
```

animal could be either an instanceof a Cat or a Bear. The animal passed in from my form always returns false (also if the Object's structure seems to match one of a Cat or a Bear).

Is there a way to get the type properly?

Comment: typeof just returns 'object' and not the type of the object

Comment: How is animal created ? Do you use `new Cat()` or `new Bear()` ? If you just have an object that matches the structure `instanceof` will not return true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The root of the problem is this line

> also if the Object's structure seems to match one of a Cat or a Bear

The object structure won't matter here. The `instanceof` checks whether the object was created using a constructor of `Cat` or `Bear`, e.g. `new Cat()` (and actually if both extend `Animal` then the `instanceof Animal` would be `true` for both).

Normally TypeScript uses [duck typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) to resolve whether the interface is matching the object structure and this is where the similar object structure could work. However `instanceof` is JavaScript (because is executed in the runtime), so there is no much more TypeScript can do there. That is why it does not work as you might have expected.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I currently have an array of Cats in my component and use an ngFor to loop over this in the form. Then I use the function getTypeOfAnimal in the form and the cat is passed in from the ngFor.

So it doesn't really get created with new Cat() I think... Or does it when in my model a constructor is defined?

Comment: yes, check the place where the cats array is populated. What you can do is checking for the property that the cat does have and the bear does not, this would mean it is a `Cat`. This is what is called duck typing, it is dirty, but it may work for a small case

Comment: Thanks for your answer again. What I did now is checking for some custom properties in the function.

So for example 

getTypeOfAnimal(animal) {
     if(animal.hasOwnProperty('property1'){
        return "cat";
     } else if (animal.hasOwnProperty('property2') {
       return "bear";
     }
}

Maybe not really the solution I expected but it works for now...

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with classes in a hierarchy, you can use `instanceof`:

```
class Animal {
    name: string;
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    purrs: boolean;
}

class Bear extends Animal {
    growls: boolean;
}


const animal = new Cat();
console.log(animal instanceof Cat); // true
console.log(animal instanceof Bear); // false
```

When dealing with structural types that you want to narrow, you can use a custom type guard:

```
const structuralBear = {
    name: 'Paddington',
    growls: false
};

console.log(structuralBear instanceof Cat); // false
console.log(structuralBear instanceof Bear); // false

function isBeary(obj: any): obj is Bear {
    console.log(typeof obj.growls);
    return (typeof obj.name === 'string' && typeof obj.growls === 'boolean');
}

console.log(isBeary(structuralBear));
```

This works out if something is "beary" enough for your needs...

On the whole, though, beware of needing to know too much about types in this way. The main use case is to narrow a union type.